# How to use the read function, with an unknown size

Tags: c, file

I made a function that opens a file and reads the single characters of them.

```
int getBlocks(char *file){

char c;
int line = 0;
int pos = 0;
int blocks;

FILE *inptr = fopen(file, "rt");

// Count the amount of blocks/tetriminos
while((c=fgetc(inptr))!=EOF){

    if(c == '.' || c == '#'){
        pos++;
        if(pos == 4){
            pos = 0;
            line++;
        }
    }
}

blocks = (line/4);
fclose(inptr);

return blocks;
}
```

Now I have to rewrite it, because the only functions I am allowed to use are `exit`, `open`, `close`, `write`, `read`, `malloc` and `free`.

I think I could basically use `int inptr = open(file, O_RDONLY);` instead of my `fopen` line, and simply `close(inptr);` instead of my `fclose` function.

My only problem now is `fgetc`. I am pretty sure that I can use `read` here, but according to it's definition `ssize_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbytes);` I would need to tell a fixed amount of bytes in advance, but the filesize can always differ in my case.

Do you know how I could rewrite `fgetc` here?

Comment: `int file = open(filepath, O_RDONLY); while (read(file, &chr, 1) == 1) { ... /* the rest of your code */ } ... close(file);`

Comment: I don't see the problem. Just `read` one character at a time.

Comment: Unrelated, hope they're small files. direct `read`, in general, is hideous for large numbers of small reads.. Can you do it, sure, but you can also pound nails with cooked spaghetti; doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: why read only one character at a time?  That's pretty inefficient; especially after Meltdown fixes... ;)

Comment: Only one at the time because I need to evaluate the single characters here. Probably isn't the most efficient way I know, but that's the only way I know/ I learned it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty similar with slight changes

```
char chr;
int fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1)
    reutnr -1; // Or some error integer
while (read(fd, &chr, 1) == 1) { 
    /* the rest of your code */
}
close(fd);
```

Note that one important change is that the type of `chr` is `char` and not `int`.

Instead of checking for `EOF` you simply check that `read()` returned a suitable value, ideally you should store it somewhere and check that it's `0` at the end of the loop, meaning the end of the file was reached, otherwise an error occurred.

Comment: @Robin I just noticed that in your code, you have `char c;` and that's wrong. It has to be `int c;` because `fgetc()` returns `int` and not `char`. The return value of `fgetc()` might not fit into a `char` variable.

Comment: Of course that can be slow doing a read for every character. Most real programs just pick some large buffer size--say a few Kb--then read in chunks of that size. The read() call will return with whatever bytes it could. When it returns with fewer than what you requested, you know you're at the end of the file.